# iPhone: Putting only one section of UITableView in Edit mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have three sections in my hypothetical UITableView. I'd like one section that is in editing mode. The rest of the sections to not be in editing mode. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This really shouldn't be a mystery, as it's spelled out clearly in the documentation. Simply use the datasource method

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Thanks - I was just looking for this myself and it was much easier to find it here than in the docs :-)

Comment: if you look up UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource you will see basically everything you will ever need about TableViews

Answer (score 0):

This worked great for me. In the example below section 0 is not editable whilst the other sections are.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if indexPath.section == 0{
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```