# How to I create this tableview with two dynamic sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on an iOS application and I can't figure out how to implement this feature. I really want the feature to look like this

[image: https://imgur.com/TgQzfCi.]

But I have no clue how to do it, I was thinking of creating a table view with two sections, but I don't know how to toggle the second section based off the first and allow the user to add, delete, and edit the rows in the second section. Where do I start if I want to do something like this?

Comment: Give it a try first, then if you're still stumped, come back, post the code you tried, then we can help you.

Comment: Good reference on Tables https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39220831/enable-editing-mode-just-for-a-section-in-uitableview) if you need help on toggle edit mode for only 1 section

Comment: https://github.com/younatics/ExpandableCell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone: Putting only one section of UITableView in Edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579273/iphone-putting-only-one-section-of-uitableview-in-edit-mode)

Comment: collect some knowledge [from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview), for instance.